# SQL Query count greatest number of children

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to display information regarding the parent with the greatest number of children. The query below works, however, I am having trouble adding more column names from the family table e.g `first_name`, `last_name`. What am I missing?

SQL Statement
-- Display parent with the greatest number of children

```
SELECT w.Parent, count(*) AS 'Number of children'
FROM family w,
     family m
WHERE w.Parent = m.pid
GROUP BY w.Parent
HAVING count(*) =
    (SELECT MAX (mycount)
    FROM
        (SELECT count(*) mycount
        FROM family
        GROUP BY Parent) a);
```

Current Output
Parent = 101 Number of children = 4

Comment: FYI, You can only select 1 answer, so select the one that you most prefer, but you can upvote *ANY* or *ALL* answers to recognise their assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax!

Start with a query to get the parents with the most children:

```
select top (1) with ties parent, count(*) as cnt
from family f
group by parent
order by cnt desc
```

Then join back to `family` to get more information:

```
select f.*
from family f join
     (select top (1) with ties parent, count(*) as cnt
      from family f
      group by parent
      order by cnt desc
     ) pc
     on pc.parent = f.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the `first_name` or `last_name` for the parent, you could do the following:

```
SELECT w.Parent, MIN(w.first_name) AS first_name, MIN(w.last_name) AS last_name, count(*) AS 'Number of children' 
FROM family w, family m 
WHERE w.Parent = m.pid 
GROUP BY w.Parent 
HAVING count() = (
    SELECT MAX (mycount) 
    FROM (
        SELECT count(*) mycount FROM family GROUP BY Parent
    ) 
a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join (properly) and group:

```
select top (1) P.First_Name, P.Last_Name
    , count(*) [Number of children]
from dbo.Family P
inner join dbo.Family C on C.Parent = P.id
group by P.First_Name, P.Last_Name
order by [Number of children] desc;
```

Then for every additional column you display from `P`, group by the same column.